# Is it possible to define a public variable in a private method?

Tags: c#, private, public, access-modifiers

I have a class with 2 private methods. In method A, I have defined a variable, say varA counting sth. In Method B, it is required to use varA again.

However, varA is just sth like temp counter, which seems should not be regarded as an attribute of the class.

So how do I access varA in private method B? Is it possible to define varA as public in a private method A?

```
public class MyClass{

  private void methodA(){
     private int varA;
     varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
     .......
  }
  private void methodB(){
    //here, I need to access varA again
    //but I don't want to define varA as attribute of MyClass
  }

}
```

**Edit:**
Context of the class:
Actually method A and method B can be run independently. But just this time I run method A then method B. And I have to use GetSingleValesFromDB() to get the value again in method B, like what I did in method A.
However, the value got from DB will not change even there is a time gap between execution of method A and method B, so I don't want to run GetSingleValesFromDB() again in method B, which consumes DB and connection resources. Rather I like to just reuse the value of varA.

Comment: please share your code here

Comment: No method, no matter what its protection level, exposes any of its *local* variables in a manner in which it would make sense to ascribe a protection  level to it.

Comment: why you should not define outside the methods? if you declare variable inside method then scope will be within the method.

Comment: You don't declare public or private anything inside a method, you only declare local variables. You can declare variables *outside* the method that can be made public or private however.

Comment: The code you've edited in doesn't *compile*. As I said, there's no protection level on local variables, so `private int varA;` within `methodA` is an error. Rather than this broken proposal, maybe flesh out in more detail what *problem* you're trying to solve, and why you think sharing local variables is part of the solution.

Comment: re: `Damien_The_Unbeliever` I want to share the variable because :
Usually I run method A then method B . I have  to use GetSingleValesFromDB() to get the value again in method B. However, the value got from DB will not change even there is a time gap between execution of method A and method B, so I don't want to run GetSingleValesFromDB() again, which consumes resources. Rather I like to just reuse the value of varA.

Comment: Is there, then, a dependency that `methodB` may only be called after `methodA`? That's usually a sign of bad class design. Ideally, all of the code would go in a single method and you'd provide flags/callbacks to allow the caller to a) decide if the `methodB` processing should go ahead and b) perform processing where it currently does between calls.

Comment: Re `Damien_The_Unbeliever` , there is no this dependency. It is **NOT** the case that every time running method A + method B. Sorry I mistyped.
Actually method A and B can be run independently. But just this time I run method A then B and I don't want to re-run GetSingleValesFromDB().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To start with, the example code that you've provided won't compile because a variable declared within a method is automatically local - that is, it is always *private to that method*. Adding public/private access modifiers is therefore not valid. I'm also assuming that there is some other method ("`methodC`") that calls `methodA` & `methodB` (as they're both private),  so your starting code should look something like this:

```
public class MyClass{

  private void methodA(){
    int varA;
    varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
    .......
  }

  private void methodB(){
    DoSomething(varA);
    .......
  }

  public void methodC(){
    methodA();
    methodB();
  }
}
```

You have a couple of approaches to sharing the value of `varA` between `methodA` and `methodB`:

- **Retrieve the value twice**

The simplest option is to redeclare and retrieve `varA` in each method so you have two distinct, local variables, thus:

```
public class MyClass{

  private void methodA(){
    int varA;
    varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
    .......
  }

  private void methodB(){
    int varA;
    varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
    DoSomething(varA);
    .......
  }

  public void methodC(){
    methodA();
    methodB();
  }
}
```

If `GetSingleValesFromDB` is a cheap call and not going to change between running `methodA` and `methodB`, this is a safe and easy approach; however, given your question (and the implied called to a database) I assume this won't meet your needs.

- **Share the variable as well as the value**

You can promote the variable from being method-local to a private class member, which makes it (and therefore its value) available to all methods:

```
public class MyClass{

  private int varA;

  private void methodA(){
     varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
     .......
  }

  private void methodB(){
    DoSomething(varA);
    .......
  }

  public void methodC(){
    methodA();
    methodB();
  }
}
```

However, if this value is liable to change from one execution of `methodA`/`methodB` to the next, making the variable a class member gives the wrong impression - implying (as you suggest in your question) that it is a property of the class when it is actually state relating to the method execution.

- **Pass a state object**

Wrap shared state in a small data object and pass that to both methods:

```
public class MyClass{

  private class MyMethodState
  {
    public int varA;
  }

  private void methodA(MyMethodState state){
    state.varA = GetSingleValesFromDB();
    .......
  }

  private void methodB(MyMethodState state){
    DoSomething(state.varA);
    .......
  }

  public void methodC(){
    var state = new MyMethodState();
    methodA(state);
    methodB(state);
  }
}
```

The value of `varA` provided in `methodA` will then be carried between method calls, and tidied up when the overall method execution (here represented by `methodC`) finishes.
I think this is closest to what you're looking for, as it persists the value of `varA` between methods & clearly identifies what the value you're storing is for, and how long it "lives" within the program execution. You may want to expand `MyMethodState` into a full class with its own methods if it grows too large, but for these simple calls a plain data object should do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

The only way would be for it to be on the class itself, which you say you do not want to do.

I'm not sure the reason for that? Have you considered making a private variable on the class so that only members of the class can access it?

Answer (score 0):

if you declare the variable inside a method then you can not access it from another one, you can achieve this way

```
public class MyClass
    {

        private int MethodA()
        {
            int varA = GetSingleValesFromDB()
            // do other this using varA
            // then return
            return varA;
        }

        private void MethodB()
        {
           int varB = MethodA(); // this case varA will assign to varB
           // then use varB for anything
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want to generate members you can generate a dictionary with your desired objects.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private IDictionary<string, object> session = new Dictionary<string, object>();

    private void methodA()
    {
        session["varA"] = GetSingleValesFromDB();
    }

    private void methodB()
    {
        var varA = session["varA"];
    }
}
```